# Samsung Series 5 - Maximum RAM support

Tags: laptop, memory, ultrabook

What is the maximum amount of memory that the Samsung Series 5 Ultrabook can support?

Answer (score 5):

So, I have a Samsung Series 5 Ultrabook laptop, which has been pretty nice, but I'm getting rid of it. Anyhow, while I'm waiting for my new laptop to arrive, I purchased a 16GB (2x8GB) kit of RAM.

I wanted to test my new RAM, and at the same time, I figured I would see if I could install one of the 8GB SO-DIMMS into the Samsung Series 5. The Series 5 has a soldered-on, non-removable 4GB stick of RAM (don't know where it sits physically). Previously, I had installed an additional 4GB stick of RAM in the single, removable slot, to bring it up to 8GB total.

It turns out that you CAN install an 8GB SO-DIMM into the single, removable slot, to achieve a maximum amount of 12GB of RAM. Previously, I had thought that the maximum RAM for the Samsung Series 5 was 8GB (4GB non-removable + 4GB removable).

The model number of this unit is: NP530U4B-A01US

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use this way! I have the Brazilian version of Samsung Ultrabook Series 5 with 8 GB on removable slot. Working!!

By the way, running the command:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 16
```

I have this info:

```
    Handle 0x0036, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
    Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 4
```

See the "Maximum Capacity" line... maybe support a 16 GB module, but
that should cost the price of a human organ on the black market!